# Filling a form in an Angular.js app using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, testing, phantomjs

I want to test AngularJS application using PhantomJS. First step is to fill login form with `username` field (let's assume there are no other fields).
Normally (in real browser) this field is controlled by Angular (it has `ng-model` attribute) and the whole form has `ng-submit` attribute.

So in PhantomJS script I do

1. input username

   ```
   page.evaluate(function () {
       document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = 'tester';
   });
   ```
2. take screenshot and see that 'tester' is present in input

   ```
   page.render('myfile.jpg');
   ```
3. click on submit button:

   ```
   page.evaluate(function () {
       document.getElementById('go').click();
   });
   ```
4. take another screenshot.

What I see happens is that button gets clicked, but the message is displayed which says that the value of `username` is empty. So I guess the model was not properly updated.
I also tried to set these values using jQuery - same result.

How do I correctly input values into fields controlled by angular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhantomJS provides the [`sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) function which can be used to implement a rudimentary `sendKeys`, but you need to focus on the element first:

```
function sendKeys(page, selector, keys){
    page.evaluate(function(selector){
        // focus on the text element before typing
        var element = document.querySelector(selector);
        element.click();
        element.focus();
    }, selector);
    page.sendEvent("keypress", keys);
}
sendKeys(page, "*[name=username]", "tester");
```

You might want to checkout either [protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) which seems to be tailored for Angular.js testing or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) which builds on top of PhantomJS with a much nicer API.

Comment: I had similar issues and **[this example](http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-amazon-using-phantomjs-working-example/)** by [Code Epicenter](http://code-epicenter.com/) is by far the best I have found, which is also currently tested on my local Angular app. There are examples for [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) also.